# Unable to access a nested object from Play Framework template

Tags: java, playframework

I have an object that references two child objects and I return it to the view just like I do with any other variable.

```
public class Object1 extends ArrayList<Object2> {
    private List<Object2> obj2 = new ArrayList<Object2>;
    private Object3 obj3;

    public List<Object2> getObject2() {
        return this.obj2;
    }

    public Object3 getObject3() {
        return this.obj3;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object2 o2) {
        //some other code goes here
        return super.add(o2);
    }
}

public class Object2  {
   int applianceId;
   String status;
}

public class Object3 {
   int member3;
   String member4;
}
```

Object1 is assigned to variable obj1 in my template. The problem is that if I call `getObject2()`, I get nothing, though I can access `getObject3()` just fine. What's really odd is that if I access obj1 without a getter, it contains everything that SHOULD be returned by `getObject2()`.

So, I would expect this to work, but it doesn't:

```
@for(a <-obj1.getObject2()){
    @a.member1
    @a.member2
}
```

It returns nothing.

However, this does return the data from object 2:

```
@for(a <-obj1){
    @a.applianceId
    @a.status
}
```

The results are: 3046 GREEN 3066 GREEN 3086 GREEN 3126 RED 3166 RED 3026 RED 3146 RED

Can anyone explain WHY this happens and how to rectify it?

Comment: Can you provide the compiler error!?

Comment: This does not make sense. 1) You have two private fields with the same name; 2) Your fields are private and there is no setters/parameter constructor: how those fields get assigned?

Comment: There is no compiler error, nor a runtime error. My expectation is that if I have two getters, I should be able to call them from the view and retrieve their contents, but that's not what happens.

I can retrieve only object via it's getter. The other object's contents are part of the PARENT object itself, not it's getter. This is not correct behavior.

I also corrected a bug in the example code above.

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns nothing", is `obj1.getObject2()` returning null, is `a` null, empty fields, what? However the issue does not seem to be in the code you have posted, we have no idea what the rest of your code is doing but I suspect you have made an error somewhere that you are not showing us, could you post an sscce.

Comment: I revised the code above to more closely match the real world code.

The issue seems to stem from the fact that Object1 extends ArrayList<Object2>. All I was doing was overriding the add() method so I could insert some extra functionality.

Removing "extends ArrayList<Object2>" resolved the issue, though I'm not understanding WHY extending the ArrayList class caused this.

Comment: Could you please confirm that my answer solved your issue by accepting it, otherwise please post more details so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example I gave doesn't show how I go about populating the objects, but I assure you they were populated.

The issue seems to stem from the fact that Object1 extends ArrayList. All I was doing was overriding the add() method so I could insert some extra functionality. Removing "extends ArrayList" resolved the issue, though I'm not understanding WHY extending the ArrayList class caused this. Perhaps a quirk in Play Framework?

Answer (score 0):

You never add anything to `obj2`.

When you remove the `extends ArrayList<Object2>` then in the `add()` method you must be changing `super.add(o2)` to `obj2.add(o2)` and then something **will be** added to the `obj2` instance and therefore you get the data like you are seeing.

I think you do not need the following code as it is confusing you:

```
private List<Object2> obj2 = new ArrayList<Object2>;

public List<Object2> getObject2() {
    return obj2;
}
```

When you call `Object1.add(Object2)` it only gets added to the instance of Object1 and is stored in the `List` in the superclass not in the `obj2` instance.

So calling `obj1.getObject2()` in the template (or anywhere else for that matter) will return an empty `ArrayList<Object2>` always.

It makes sense to me that you would get the data that you *added* by doing:

```
for(Object2 obj: obj1) {
    // do something with the data
}
```

or

```
@for(a <-obj1){
    @a.applianceId
    @a.status
}
```

What is your problem with doing this?

Or remove the `extends ArrayList<Object2>` and access the data with the methods you have written.

Basically you must take care that you are storing the data where you expect. If you are using Eclipse (or other IDE) I highly recommend that you debug it and set breakpoints in the methods where you are adding/accessing the data and see what the lists contain, they have handy views to let you see all the fields and objects in scope.

Comment: Myexample doesn't show you everything I do when it comes to object instantiation, etc. I more or less answered my own question above, though the root cause is still a bit of a mystery.